# C String Error - Need to understand code

Tags: c, string

code isnt working on line 19 & 20
i'm trying to get a string named hotel...
when i put gets(hotel) almost over everything surprisingly code starts working...but not in the middle of the code.!!!!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
char topping[24];
char hotel[50];
int slices;
int month,day,year,i;
float cost;
printf("how much a pizza cost in your area? ");
printf("enter in $XX.XX\n");
scanf("$%f",&cost);
printf("what is your favorite one word pizza topping?\n");
scanf("%s",&topping);
printf("how many slices of %s of pizza \n",topping);
scanf("%d",&slices);
printf("which is your favorite hotel in town?\n");
gets(hotel);
printf("what is today's date (enter in XX/XX/XXXX format)\n");
scanf("%d/%d/%d",&day,&month,&year);
printf("\n\n\n\n\nwhy not treat yourself %d slices of %s pizza in %s on %d/%d/%d it will cost you only %.2f",slices,topping,hotel,day,month,year,cost);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: by lines 19 & 20, do you mean the last scanf and the last printf?  How are they not working?  Can you re-phrase the question to be more clear?

Comment: actuly im trying to get a string from user through gets(hotel) but when i run this code..gets(hotel) not worked..nd it skips to the next printf which is what is today's date?

Comment: I don't understand why this is being voted down so much. The question was obvious to me at first glance (I answered a similar one last week so it was on my mind), but doubly so after running the code and confirming my hunch. The post could be more clear, sure, but I don't think it deserves -8 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same thing I talked about recently here: [D lang - Using read and readln() in the same program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900467/d-lang-using-read-and-readln-in-the-same-program/24900768#24900768) although in C instead of D so the solution is slightly different but same explanation.

The scanf stops on whitespace, which is a newline... which gets sees as the end of input and thus reads an empty line.

The solution is to consume that newline before continuing:

```
printf("how many slices of %s of pizza \n",topping);
scanf("%d",&slices);
fgetc(stdin); // ADDED THIS LINE TO READ PAST THE NEW LINE CHARACTER
printf("which is your favorite hotel in town?\n");
gets(hotel);
```

PS don't use `gets`, use `fgets(hotel, 50, stdin);` instead. The `50` there is the size of the buffer, ensuring it doesn't overflow.

Comment: You should only allow 49, need space for the null terminator.

Comment: `fgets` takes care of that automatically... from the man page: 
       fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream  and
       stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
       EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the  buffer.
       A '\0' is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Comment: I stand corrected, been a while since I have done inputs like this

Comment: Me too, I had to look it up myself :-) (I actually haven't written C at all for a pretty long time now. I think there's another solution other than fgetc but that's the one I remembered.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I would change.

1. When you are reading topping & hotel, they are strings, you do not need to pass that by reference.  So pass scanf("%s", topping);
2. When you are doing the strings, you want to make sure you don't allow the user to overfill the array.  See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) for an example of how to limit the input size.