# can't readf to the same variable twice

Tags: d

For this simple code:

```
long l;
readf("%d", &l);
readf("%d", &l);
```

when I enter 20 as the second number it throws an exception

```
exception: std.conv.ConvException@/usr/include/dlang/dmd/std/conv.d(1995):
```

Unexpected '2' when converting from type LockingTextReader to type long

Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's still a newline sitting in the buffer after the first one that needs to be consumed.

Similar to what I wrote about here: [D lang - Using read and readln() in the same program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900467/d-lang-using-read-and-readln-in-the-same-program/24900768#24900768)

the same fix should work.

```
long l;
readf(" %d", &l); // note the leading space
writeln("Got ", l);
readf(" %d", &l); // and again
writeln("Got ", l);
```

Comment: it's funny cause it works fine in C using scanf without doing this

Comment: Aye, scanf automatically skips the leading whitespace... though it would leave a trailing newline in the buffer (try doing a call to `fgets` right after a call to `scanf` and notice how it immediately returns an empty line..). readf doesn't but the space in there can do it. BTW this is one reason why I like to tell people in D not to be afraid to just call the C functions they know, since they still work exactly the same way too.